# Adding a Flow for writing to a Kafka subscriber

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, reactive-kafka

I need to build the following graph:

```
val graph = getFromTopic1 ~> doSomeWork ~> writeToTopic2 ~> commitOffsetForTopic1
```

but trying to implement it in Reactive Kafka has me down a rabbit hole. And that seems wrong because this strikes me as a relatively common use case: I want to move data between Kafka topics while guaranteeing At Least Once Delivery Semantics.

Now it's no problem at all to write in parallel

```
val fanOut = new Broadcast(2)
val graph = getFromTopic1 ~> doSomeWork ~> fanOut ~> writeToTopic2
                                           fanOut ~> commitOffsetForTopic1
```

This code works because `writeToTopic2` can be implemented with `ReactiveKafka#publish(..)`, which returns a `Sink`. But then I lose ALOS guarantees and thus data when my app crashes.

So what I really need is to write a Flow that writes to a Kafka topic. I have tried using `Flow.fromSinkAndSource(..)` with a custom `GraphStage` but run up against type issues for the data flowing through; for example, what gets committed in `commitOffsetForTopic1` should not be included in `writeToTopic2`, meaning that I have to keep a wrapper object containing both pieces of data all the way through. But this conflicts with the requirements that `writeToTopic2` accept a `ProducerMessage[K,V]`. My latest attempt to resolve this ran up against private and final classes in the reactive kafka library (extending/wrapping/replacing the underlying SubscriptionActor).

I don't really want to maintain a fork to make this happen. What am I missing? Why is this so hard? Am I somehow trying to build a pathological graph node or is this use case an oversight ... or is there something completely obvious I have somehow missed in the docs and source code I've been digging through?

Current version is 0.10.1. I can add more detailed information about any of my many attempts upon request.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/producer.html#producer-as-a-flow) seems to be what you're looking for. There's even an example which seems to be doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but this is Akka Streams Kafka 0.16. We're using Reactive Kafka 0.10.1. I know it's possible to do this in general - my problem is that I have an existing library in use in a variety of services and it should be possible to do this without a major rewrite.

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry. For some reason I thought that 0.10 is the latest version of Reactive Kafka. Indeed, 0.10 doesn't seem to contain such a thing.

Comment: In order to use this I'd need to upgrade our Kafka to 10+. Pretty big scope creep for that, though, considering how many services would need to be upgraded.